# MySQL Timestamp return as datetime, not integer

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have MySQL table, where column `_update` is `timestamp` type. I have problem, and don't understand, why when I do select this column, is return in datetime format, not in integer?
In JavaScript Unix timestamp is returned as integer, in PHP time() is as integer, but in MySQL this is datetime? Why?

I know, that I can use bigint type, but I want add timestamp to row, when I insert data from phpmyadmin, and update timestamp, when data is update (this is possible to set only in timestamp type column).

Comment: Nowhere in the docs it's said that it's a **Unix** timestamp at all.

Comment: You have `timestamp` data type and you get `timestamp` as returned value unless you manipulate it to return `unix_timestamp`.

Comment: I have default settings in config phpmyadmin, but when I have insert data, in `_update` is input with datetime format, when I want numbers value

Comment: I found 2 sql function to CONVERT data: UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME()

Answer (score 0):

I guess the doubt comes from the incorrect assumption that *timestamp* always refers to [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). However, it's a rather generic English word that's widely used in IT for fairly [different time-related concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp).

In the case of [MySQL `TIMESTAMP` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html), while it's true that it's stored internally as Unix timestamp:

> `TIMESTAMP` values are stored as the number of seconds since the epoch
>   ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC).

... such detail is mostly irrelevant (as most internal representations are) because the interface is the same as any other date type: a string in a fixed human-readable format, e.g.:

```
'2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'
```

And, as in any other date column type, you have the corresponding functions to convert from/to string whenever you have/need a different string format:

- [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: But I don't understand, why type `timestamp` isn't return number? In many pleaces is wrote that this is numbers of second, and in many programer language function returns number of seconds, number, not datetime :-) now, in my project I use this functions to convert datetime UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME()

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with **incorrect assumption that timestamp always refers to Unix time**.

Comment: I had the same problem, as the name timestamp is defined as a number of seconds, we do expect an integer, but the database stores the number in "date time" format, making a confusion while trying to format the number.

Comment: @Gustavo I'll be glad to correct or rephrase any incorrect statement in my answer (I'm not a native speaker and my assumptions about the meaning of the word "timestamp" can easily he flawed) but the link I found seems to support the idea that it's just time information and not even needs to be a figure. Plus MySQL does store this column type as number.